# Is there a name or explanation for the behaviour of writing the second letter first?

Tags: psychology, behavior, writing

When I am writing (pen and paper) I  sometimes write the second letter of a word first. I write it like the first letter, so capitalized if that applies. I notice this problem the second I put it on paper, but that somehow doesn't change the fact that it is still happening. I tried to monitor this behaviour to see how and when it is happening, and found out these few things:

- it always happens when I start to write  something after I stopped. So when I writing something continuously it doesn't happen, but when I stop my writing to take a sip of tea for example, it does happen  with the first word I write.
- it is always the second letter. Never the third letter, or another, always the first.
- a few other people I told about this problem said they also experienced it the same way.
- it doesn't happen when I am copying something directly out of a book etc. Only when I have the word or sentence in my head and want to write it down. But, when I read a sentence in a book, memorize it and then write it down without looking at the book again, it does happen sometimes.
- there doesnt seem to be a pattern as to when it happens. Everytime it happened I wrote some keywords, and there is no logical pattern. A few of them were tired/not tired, boring/fun, school/free time, dutch/english (dutch is my first language). They all seem to appear in every possible combination completely random.

Comment: I often have this problem. It seems like a mismatch between thinking speed and (physical) writing speed. Like I am thinking the second letter at the time my hand starts writing what should be the first letter. Usually this happens when I am writing in a hurry or not paying attention. My only solution is to slow down and consciously think of the letters as I write them. But I don't know if there is an official condition that describes this.

Comment: Can somebody explain why this is off topic? I am not asking about the behaviour of an individual person. I am asking about a behaviour, and giving a specific case as an example. I don't want 'help' with a problem, I am interested in this behaviour and curious as to where it comes from and how it can be explained. I think that is ontopic here?

Comment: Can I get an explanation as to why it is closed please? See my previous comment for my reaction.

Comment: I can see see where you are coming from. I think there is a more general scientific question in there. But it is framed in a fairly personal way and it is somewhat specific to your circumstances. Perhaps try to edit the question to frame it as a more general scientific question.

Comment: I face the same problem. I am a programmer by profession. I never face this problem while typing. But when I am writing on paper, I face this problem quite frequently. And its not something I have been facing since childhood. It developed recently during last few years when I started typing more on keyboard and writing less on paper. One possible explanation I can think of is that I can type much faster than I can write and I feel it could be related to that. Slowing down does help